# Different block size in block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-programming, block-matrices

I am following a book and having trouble understanding.

so from Section 6.6.2 page 496, i have

```
A = NxN matrix
b = Nx1 vector
c = Nx1 vector
```

from Section 14.3.2 I have,

[image]

And this is what author says, 
[image]

so now q = \begin{bmatrix}
  -c_0\; \\ b_0\;
\end{bmatrix}

lets assume from section 6.6.2,

```
A = 3x3 matrix
b = 3x1 vector
c = 3x1 vector
```

so $c_0\; = -2b^TA$ = 1x3 matrix

$b_0\;$ = \begin{bmatrix}
  b\; \\ c - b\;
\end{bmatrix}  = 6x1 matrix

so for q upper block has 3 columns while lower has 1. what wrong am i doing ? And same thing is happening with M.